# Insert into database in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to insert data into MySQL table in yii2 but it gives me errors.

I have a textbox in the view. It is meant to get the data the user inputs in the textbox with `name=Topic[topic];` and insert it into the database.

When I try it a different way like  `$topic->topic = 'good things';` it works well, but when I try to change it like `$topic->topic = $topic_data['topic'];.`
**I get this error**:

```
Undefined index: topic`
```

This is the controller:

```
use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;;

use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;

    public function actionCompose()
    {
          $topic= new Topic(); 

       $topic_data = Yii::$app->request->post('Topic', []);

        $topic->creator = Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
          $topic->topic = $topic_data['topic'];

         $topic->save();
           return $this->render('compose');
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use common\models\Comment;
use common\models\Users;
use common\models\Candidate;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
       <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

  <input type="name" class="form-control"  required="true" name="Topic[topic]" id="topic" placeholder="topic">

   <?= Html::submitButton('My Yii Application', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>   
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

How do I fix this or is their a better way to do it?

Comment: Show us what `var_dump($topic_data)` shows you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using proper $model->load

```
   $topic= new Topic(); 
   $topic->load($_POST)
   $topic->creator = Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
   $topic->save();
   return $this->render('compose');
```

Comment: it worked. how come it knows the right colon it the table to insert to . i mean the  $topic->load($_POST)....

Comment: The function  load is base on the model and using the info provided by active record  the model know the how the fields are mapped to the column ... when you use model->load  yii2 load in model fields all the column matching the model name and the column name  ..like you can see in this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail

Comment: got it i understand

Comment: what if I don't want to use `$topic->load($_POST)` ?

Comment: @MrFaisal   then you must assign the each $topic attribute the related  $_POST value ..